# Using wp_send_json_success instead of $result['message'], die, etc

Tags: ajax, json

My usual ajax function looks like this:

```
function get_modal_playlist_classplan( $odv_video_id ) {
    check_ajax_referer($_REQUEST['nonce'], "my_cool_nonce", false);

    $result['type'] = "success";

    $result['message'] = "Booooo";

    if ( $some_test === true ) {
        $result['message'] = "Yay";
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $result = json_encode($result);
        echo $result;
    } else {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }

    die();
}
```

How do I replace my approach with the use of [wp_send_json_success](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success) (and wp_send_json_error)?

I tried replacing `$result['message'] = "yay"` with:

```
$return = array(
    'message' => 'yay',
    'some_other_data' => $_REQUEST['hello'] . ' world'
);

wp_send_json_success( $return );
```

But the ajax request fails.

Comment: Instead of using the old `admin-ajax.php` system, have you considered using the modern REST API endpoint system instead? Also keep in mind that `$_REQUEST` isn't just `GET` and `POST`, it can be `ENV`, `COOKIE`, `SESSION` too so there are security consequences

Comment: In other words, having javascript send a get request directly to a restful endpoint?

Comment: the javascript is almost identical but the API would do all of the things for you by default that you're asking how best to do in this question. The answer would become `return $result;`